# Why is there no option to download 32 bit or 64 bit for Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, iso, downloads, compatibility, architecture

You go to official site to download ISO image. There is only one "Download" button. No option to choose between 32 or 64 bit. My PC is 64 bit, I don't want to download 32 bit version.

Comment: arm64, amd64 - both are 32-bit, and most people use x86_64 or amd64.  32-bit was last available for Ubuntu 17.04 (2017-April or long ago, much later for flavors of Ubuntu)

Comment: Ubuntu use to have both 32 bit and 64 bit options and two download buttons.  Ubuntu only has 64 bit now so only needs the one button.

Answer (score 3):

There is no option to choose between 32 and 64-bit iso, because only 64-bit is available.

If you want a 64-bit release, I see no problem at all.